# PHP Insert Into is not beeing executed

Tags: php, mysql

Insert INTO is not beeing executed even though the connection is successfull and manually using the query on the Database works.
The Database Server is a MySql Database Server.

This is where i call the Function

```
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
if (isset($_POST["btn_addevent"])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $eventname = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["txt_eventname"]));
    $eventdate = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["dt_date"]));
    $eventtime = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["tm_time"]));
    $eventgame = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["txt_game"]));
    fcn_execSql("INSERT INTO db_Projekt.tbleventstest (dtUserName, dtEventName, dtEventTime, dtEventdate,dtGame)VALUES('$username','$eventname','$eventtime','$eventdate','$eventgame')");
}
```

This is the Function To Execute the SQL

```
function fcn_execSql($thissql, $return = "default") {
    //defining the values needed to establish a connection
    if ($_SESSION["isdefined"] == false) {
        define('DB_SERVER', '31.220.59.149');
        define('DB_USERNAME', 'USERNAME');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'PASSWORD');
        define('DB_DATABASE', 'db_Projekt');
        $_SESSION["isdefined"] = true;
    }
    //connecting using the values defined before
    $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
    //trying to connect
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    //executing a query and writing its result into a variable
    $result = $conn->query($thissql);
    if ($result == false) {
        $conn->close();
        die;
    }
    if ($return == "JSON") {                                          //query
        $array = mysqli_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result
        $returnedjson = json_encode($array);
        echo $returnedjson;
    }
    if (strpos($thissql, 'SELECT') !== false) {
        $array = array();
        $i = 0;
        $rowcount = $result->num_rows;
        if ($rowcount > 0) {
            //closing the SQL Connection again
            $conn->close();
            //returning query results
            if ($rowcount > 1) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $array[] = $row;
                }
            } else {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                return $row;
            }
            return $array;
        } //returning false in case of a failure and closing the connection
        else {
            $conn->close();
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $conn->close();
        return true;
    }
}
```

The Function is beeing successfully used here

```
if (isset($_POST["btn_register"]) && strlen($_POST["txt_username"]) > 3 && strlen($_POST["txt_password"]) > 3) {
    $username = $_POST["txt_username"];
    $password = md5($_POST["txt_password"]);
    $email = $_POST['txt_email'];
    $activationcode = rand(10000, 99999);
    fcn_execSql("INSERT INTO db_Projekt.tblUsers (idUsername,dtPassword,dtEmail,dtActivationcode)VALUES('$username','$password','$email','$activationcode')");
    sendmail($email, $activationcode, $username);
}
```

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3Lzu.png)

Comment: This code look like a heaven for sql injection attacks

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake. `hemlentities` is **NOT** a SQL escaping method.

Comment: I don't know where you learned to write SQL code like this, but this is really, really dangerous code. If this is deployed anywhere publicly accessible you're at extreme risk of a compromise.

Comment: Also - You have a column named `dtUserName`, but in the query you reference to it as `idUsername` (N vs. n)

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication) built-in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks ok to me. Are you sure all those $_POST variables are correctly set?

Also, can we see your DB structure?

**Edit:**

You are missing quotes around the

```
$eventgame
```

value at the end of the query. This may make a difference.

Comment: The Post values are correct i tried echoing the SQL and manually using it on the Data Base and it worked.The quotes didnt fix the issue.

Comment: Did you see my edit? Have you tried adding those quotes?

Comment: I did but they sadly didnt fix the issue.

Comment: Try adding some error checking in the SQL function. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php